# What exactly prevents the UI freeze when using the await keyword?

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

In a windows forms app, suppose button click event does cpu intensive or io bound work then it freezes the ui.

This is because the main thread is responsible to refresh the ui and run the button click event, but since it is busy with the click event it can't refresh the ui.

This can be solved using 2 ways:

1. Io bound: use async await
2. Cpu bound: use Task.Run.. this will run the work in a separate thread.

I am assuming in windows form app there is 1 thread that does the ui refresh and event code execution.

In case of point 2 it is clear that ui thread is free because the cpu bound work is done by separate thread.

This question is about point 1 - async await. Assuming the work is a http api call that takes 10 seconds.

When I use await keyword I am told that it will release the thread into the thread pool. Another person told me that it will return the control to the caller.

What exactly is the reason why the ui is no longer frozen?

Comment: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) -- [Asynchronous programming scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) -- *When I use await keyword I am told that it will release the thread into the thread pool*: this is not correct, you'll see why. -- *it will return the control to the caller*: this is, in practice, correct.

Comment: Caller means calling function?

Comment: The execution context.

Comment: If you're interested in the machinery behind `async/await`, this may be useful: [Dissecting the async methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) -- The two articles linked at the bottom are also worth reading (it means you *must* read them :) The second article leads to a third one that you *should* read, too.

Comment: Also see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html